# Fastest way to find the nth permutation

Tags: algorithms, permutations

What is the fastest way to compute the n-th permutation? Use whatever ordering makes sense. All the algorithms I've found are for enumerating all the permutations.

Comment: Looks like this belongs in programmers.stackexchange.com (or possibly math.stackexchange.com, because it's basically a math question but not research-level mathematics).

Answer (score 2):

Let $m$ be the permutation order.

It's easy to compute $n$-th inversion table by representing $n$ in the [mixed radix system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) with bases from $1$ to $m$, and then turn it into a permutation (e.g., see [this discussion](https://reddit.com/r/coding/comments/a3ckw/programming_problem_find_a_permutation_given_its/)).

Comment: Thank you for answering! Could you elaborate on how to get the inversion table from the mixed radix system?